# Why does it call method 'isCorrect' multiple times (onClick) if I hit the button only once?

Tags: java, android

I made a simple quiz game for android, right now there's only 10 questions, and 40 answers. (4 answers for each question)
Sometimes when I hit a button it gives me more than one correct answer at a time, also it might even do it when answer's not correct.
Any idea what's wrong in this code? Cause Im not calling the isCorrect boolean method multiple times (in one click).

Code:

```
public class ETBetaActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button answer_1,
    answer_2,answer_3,
    answer_4,main;

    TextView q_textview,
    tip;

    private String a1,a2,a3,a4 = "";

    private int i1 = 0;
    public static int correct = 0;

    private boolean alive = true;

    MediaPlayer button_click;

    private String[] questions =
   {"Q1", 
    "Q2",
    "Q3", 
    "Q4",
    "Q5", //5
    "Q6", 
    "Q7", 
    "Q8", 
    "Q9",
    "Q10" //10
    };
    public static int question_amount = 10;
    private String[] answers_correct =
   {"Correct answer - 1",
    "Correct answer - 2",
    "Correct answer - 3", 
    "Correct answer - 4",
    "Correct answer - 5",
    "Correct answer - 6",
    "Correct answer - 7",
    "Correct answer - 8",
    "Correct answer - 9",
    "Correct answer - 10"
    };

    private String[][] answers_wrong = 
    { {"Q1-1", "Q1-2" , "Q1-3"},
      {"Q2-1", "Q2-2" , "Q2-3"},
      {"Q3-1", "Q3-2" , "Q3-3"},
      {"Q4-1", "Q4-2" , "Q4-3"},
      {"Q5-1", "Q5-2" , "Q5-3"},
      {"Q6-1", "Q6-2" , "Q6-3"},
      {"Q7-1", "Q7-2" , "Q7-3"},
      {"Q8-1", "Q8-2" , "Q8-3"},
      {"Q9-1", "Q9-2" , "Q9-3"},
      {"Q10-1", "Q10-2" , "Q10-3"}

    };


    List<String> question_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> answer_list_correct = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getData();
        Game(i1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (alive == false) {
        //  startActivity(new Intent("com.aleksei.etb.END"));
            return;
        }
        button_click = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button_click);
        button_click.start();
        switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.button5: //main
            break;
        case R.id.button1: //answer_1
            if(isCorrect(1))
                correct++;


            break;
        case R.id.button2: //answer_2
            if(isCorrect(2))
                correct++;

            break;
        case R.id.button3: //answer_3
            if(isCorrect(3))
                correct++;

            break;
        case R.id.button4: //answer_3
            if(isCorrect(4))
                correct++;


            break;

        default:
            break;


        }
        Game(i1);
        tip.setText("Correct answers: "+correct);
    }


    public static int getResults(){
        int value = (int) Math.floor((correct*5)/question_amount);
        if(value <= 0)
        return 1;
        else
        return value;
    }

    private boolean isCorrect(int button){
        for (int i = 0; i < answers_correct.length; i++){
        if(button == 1 && a1 == answers_correct[i]
            || button == 2 && a2 == answers_correct[i]
            || button == 3 && a3 == answers_correct[i]
            || button == 4 && a4 == answers_correct[i])
            return true;
        }
        return false; 
    }

    private void Game(int q){
        if(i1 == question_amount) { //no more questions
            startActivity(new Intent("com.aleksei.etb.END"));
            alive = false;
            return;
        }
        try {
        main.setText("Dunno");
        String answer_list[] = {
        answers_correct[q], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]     
        };

        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(answer_list));
        answer_1.setText(answer_list[0]);
        answer_2.setText(answer_list[1]);
        answer_3.setText(answer_list[2]);
        answer_4.setText(answer_list[3]);
        a1 = answer_list[0];
        a2 = answer_list[1];
        a3 = answer_list[2];
        a4 = answer_list[3];
        q_textview.setText(questions[q]);
        } catch (Exception ex){}
        i1++;
    }
    private void getData(){
        //Getting the data
        main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        answer_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        answer_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        answer_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        answer_4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        q_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        tip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answ1);

        //Making the buttons, actually work
        main.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_1.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_2.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_3.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_4.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Resets the text
        //Note to self: Replace with another ContectView
        main.setText("Begin!");
        answer_4.setText("");
        answer_3.setText("");
        answer_2.setText("");
        answer_1.setText("");
        tip.setText("");
    }

    }
```

Comment: Start the app in a debugger, place a breakpoint at the isCorrect() method, press the button, and find out where the method is being called from. Being able to do this is an important part of being a developer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following changes and see if it improves:

```
 private int questionNumber = -1;

 private void Game(int q){
    ...
    questionNumber = q;
    q_textview.setText(questions[q]);
    ...
 }

private boolean isCorrect(int button){
    if(button == 1 && a1.equals(answers_correct[questionNumber])
        || button == 2 && a2.equals(answers_correct[questionNumber])
        || button == 3 && a3.equals(answers_correct[questionNumber])
        || button == 4 && a4.equals(answers_correct[questionNumber]))
        return true;
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Storing the question number as a field eliminates the `for` loop over all the questions.
You should always use `String.equals` instead of `==`.

Comment: Dont think it also nessesary to have it = -1; , when Im doing a = q; later on, but thanks going to try this right now.