# OnClick listener acts strange (1 click - calls it more than once?)

Tags: java, android

I made a simple quiz game for android, right now there's only 10 questions, and 40 answers. (4 answers for each question) Sometimes when I hit a button it gives me more than one correct answer at a time! Any idea what's wrong with this code:

```
public class ETBetaActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button answer_1,
    answer_2,answer_3,
    answer_4,main;

    TextView q_textview,
    tip;

    private String a1,a2,a3,a4 = "";

    private int i1 = 0;
    public static int correct = 0;

    private boolean alive = true;

    MediaPlayer button_click;

    private String[] questions =
   {"Q1", 
    "Q2",
    "Q3", 
    "Q4",
    "Q5", //5
    "Q6", 
    "Q7", 
    "Q8", 
    "Q9",
    "Q10" //10
    };
    public static int question_amount = 10;
    private String[] answers_correct =
   {"Correct answer - 1",
    "Correct answer - 2",
    "Correct answer - 3", 
    "Correct answer - 4",
    "Correct answer - 5",
    "Correct answer - 6",
    "Correct answer - 7",
    "Correct answer - 8",
    "Correct answer - 9",
    "Correct answer - 10"
    };

    private String[][] answers_wrong = 
    { {"Q1-1", "Q1-2" , "Q1-3"},
      {"Q2-1", "Q2-2" , "Q2-3"},
      {"Q3-1", "Q3-2" , "Q3-3"},
      {"Q4-1", "Q4-2" , "Q4-3"},
      {"Q5-1", "Q5-2" , "Q5-3"},
      {"Q6-1", "Q6-2" , "Q6-3"},
      {"Q7-1", "Q7-2" , "Q7-3"},
      {"Q8-1", "Q8-2" , "Q8-3"},
      {"Q9-1", "Q9-2" , "Q9-3"},
      {"Q10-1", "Q10-2" , "Q10-3"}

    };


    List<String> question_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> answer_list_correct = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getData();
        Game(i1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (alive == false) {
        //  startActivity(new Intent("com.aleksei.etb.END"));
            return;
        }
        button_click = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button_click);
        button_click.start();
        switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.button5: //main
            break;
        case R.id.button1: //answer_1
            if(isCorrect(1))
                correct++;


            break;
        case R.id.button2: //answer_2
            if(isCorrect(2))
                correct++;

            break;
        case R.id.button3: //answer_3
            if(isCorrect(3))
                correct++;

            break;
        case R.id.button4: //answer_3
            if(isCorrect(4))
                correct++;


            break;

        default:
            break;


        }
        Game(i1);
        tip.setText("Correct answers: "+correct);
    }


    public static int getResults(){
        int value = (int) Math.floor((correct*5)/question_amount);
        if(value <= 0)
        return 1;
        else
        return value;
    }

    private boolean isCorrect(int button){
        for (int i = 0; i < answers_correct.length; i++){
        if(button == 1 && a1 == answers_correct[i]
            || button == 2 && a2 == answers_correct[i]
            || button == 3 && a3 == answers_correct[i]
            || button == 4 && a4 == answers_correct[i])
            return true;
        }
        return false; 
    }

    private void Game(int q){
        if(i1 == question_amount) { //no more questions
            startActivity(new Intent("com.aleksei.etb.END"));
            alive = false;
            return;
        }
        try {
        main.setText("Dunno");
        String answer_list[] = {
        answers_correct[q], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]     
        };

        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(answer_list));
        answer_1.setText(answer_list[0]);
        answer_2.setText(answer_list[1]);
        answer_3.setText(answer_list[2]);
        answer_4.setText(answer_list[3]);
        a1 = answer_list[0];
        a2 = answer_list[1];
        a3 = answer_list[2];
        a4 = answer_list[3];
        q_textview.setText(questions[q]);
        } catch (Exception ex){}
        i1++;
    }
    private void getData(){
        //Getting the data
        main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        answer_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        answer_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        answer_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        answer_4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        q_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        tip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answ1);

        //Making the buttons, actually work
        main.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_1.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_2.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_3.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_4.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Resets the text
        //Note to self: Replace with another ContectView
        main.setText("Begin!");
        answer_4.setText("");
        answer_3.setText("");
        answer_2.setText("");
        answer_1.setText("");
        tip.setText("");
    }

    }
```

I even tried something like

```
private boolean getAnswer = false;
 private String correctAnswer;



    private boolean isCorrect(int button){
        if(getAnswer == true) {
        if(button == 1 && a1 == correctAnswer
        || button == 2 && a2 == correctAnswer
        || button == 3 && a3 == correctAnswer
        || button == 4 && a4 == correctAnswer) 
        return true; 
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Inside Game(int) :

```
getAnswer = false;
correctAnswer = answers_correct[q];
```

Didnt help.

*I hope I made my self clear, if not, ask.*

Thanks.

Edit:
Tried using these in the onCreate method

```
answer_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(isCorrect(1))
                    correct++;

                 Game(i1);
                 tip.setText("Correct answers "+correct);

            }
        });

        answer_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(isCorrect(2))
                    correct++;

                 Game(i1);
                 tip.setText("Correct answers "+correct);

            }
        });

        answer_3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(isCorrect(3))
                    correct++;

                 Game(i1);
                 tip.setText("Correct answers "+correct);

            }
        });

        answer_4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(isCorrect(4))
                    correct++;

                 Game(i1);
                 tip.setText("Correct answers "+correct);

            }
        });
```

Didn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does it call method 'isCorrect' multiple times (onClick) if I hit the button only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169960/why-does-it-call-method-iscorrect-multiple-times-onclick-if-i-hit-the-button) - please don't repost the same question

Answer (score 0):

Im a little confused as to why you are having your entire activity be an on click listener instead of setting up your project similar to this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

My guess would be that both the activity view itself AND the button views are executing the onClickListener callback.

Comment: Didnt help, still the same thing. (Did everything your way)

Comment: The problem looks to be after the switch statement. You have a listener for the main activity which executes the onClick method.At the bottom of the method after the switch statement you have the tip.setText(...) In the edits you made, did you remove the implements View.OnClickListener in the class signature? unless you require an onClickListener for the entire activity, this should be removed. You just need listeners for the buttons themselves as far as I can see